# all eigenvectors and eigenvalues for this transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $\pi$ be the plane spanned up by vectors $v_1 = (1, 1, 1)$ and $v_2 = (2, 1, 3)$. Consider linear transformation that stretches the plane in the direction of $v_1$ by factor $2$ and in the direction of $v_2$ by factor $3$. Find all eigenvectors and eigenvalues for this transformation. In addition, find an explicit form of transformation matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

The problem fix the eigenvalue $\lambda_1=2$ with eigenvector $v_1$ and the eigenvalue $\lambda_2=3$ with eigenvector $v_2$.

Without other conditions the other eigenvalue $\lambda_3$ can have any real value (note that it cannot have a complex value. Whay?).

Comment: based on the Av=λv   we have Av1=2v1 and Av2= 3v2  am I right ?

Comment: Yes, but the third eigenvalue is free.

Comment: thank you when you say free, means Av3=0v3? or could you please tell me what do you mean exactly?   Av1=2v1 and Av2= 3v2   then Av3=0v3

Comment: Free means that $\lambda_3$ can be any real number.

Comment: so now let say our eigenvalues are 2,3,1 and these are vectors v1(1,0,2), v2(2,0,0), v3(0,1,0) then please how about the explicit form of transformation matrix?